# Prob. 15, Sec. 4.2, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: $\lim_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to c}f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 15, Sec. 4.2, in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be a cluster point of $A$. In addition, suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in A$, and let $\sqrt{f}$ be the function defined for $x \in A$ by $\left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$. If $\lim_{x \to c} f$ exists, prove that $\lim_{x \to c} \sqrt{f} = \sqrt{ \lim_{x \to c} f}$.

My Attempt:

> Let us put $$ L \colon= \lim_{x \to c} f(x). $$ 
>   Let us take any real number $\varepsilon > 0$.
>
> First suppose that $L = 0$. Then there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert < \varepsilon^2 $$
>   for all $x \in A$ which satisfy 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x - c \rvert < \delta. $$
>   But as $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in A$, so for all $x \in A$ for which 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta, $$
>   we have 
>   $$ f(x) = \lvert f(x) \rvert =  \lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert < \varepsilon^2, $$
>   and so 
>   $$\left\lvert  \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) - 0 \right\rvert = \sqrt{ f(x) } < \varepsilon. $$
>   Thus it follows that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) = 0 $$
>   also.

Am I right?

> Now suppose that $L \neq 0$. If $L$ were negative, then we would have $-L > 0$ and so we could find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < -L $$
>   for all $x \in A$ which satisfy 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x-c\rvert < \delta. $$
>   Thus, for all $x \in A$ which satisfy 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x-c\rvert < \delta, $$
>   we would obtain 
>   $$ L - (-L) < f(x) < L + (- L), $$
>   or 
>   $$ 2L < f(x) < 0. $$
>   But $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in A$. Thus if $L$ were negative, then we would arrive at a contradiction. So $L$ must be (strictly) positive.

Am I right?

> Now as $L > 0$ and as $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in A$, so for every point $x \in A$, we find that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) - \sqrt{L} \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \right\rvert \\
> &= \left\lvert \frac{ \left( \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L}  \right) \left( \sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}  \right)  }{  \sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}  } \right\rvert \\
> &= \left\lvert \frac{ f(x) - L  }{  \sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}  } \right\rvert \\
> &= \frac{ \left\lvert  f(x) - L \right\rvert  }{ \left\lvert  \sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L} \right\rvert  } \\
> &= \frac{ \left\lvert  f(x) - L \right\rvert  }{ \sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}   } \\
> &\leq \frac{ \left\lvert  f(x) - L \right\rvert  }{ \sqrt{L}   } \\
> &= \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{L}   }  \left\lvert  f(x) - L \right\rvert. \tag{1}
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Now as $$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L, $$
>   so we can find a real number $\delta_0 > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon \sqrt{L} $$
>   for all points $x \in A$ for which $$ 0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_0. $$
>   Thus from (1) we can conclude that, for all points $x \in A$ for which $$ \lvert x-c\rvert < \delta_0, $$
>   we end up with 
>   $$ \left\lvert \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) - \sqrt{L} \right\rvert \leq \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{L}   }  \left\lvert  f(x) - L \right\rvert < \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{L}   } \varepsilon \sqrt{L} = \varepsilon, $$
>   and hence we obtain 
>   $$ \left\lvert \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) - \sqrt{L} \right\rvert < \varepsilon. $$
>   Thus it follows that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} \left(\sqrt{f}\right)(x) = \sqrt{L}. $$

Am I right?

Is this proof good enough? What is the presentation like?

Comment: I didn't read everything in detail but looks good. Another way is to prove first that if a function is always $\ge 0$, then any limit is also $\ge 0$.